When we try to migrate embedded service deployment for enhanced bot
We retrieved network, customSite, static resource, queue, queueroutingconfig, flow, but when we tried to deployed, we received an error
Label: data value too large: ESW_EmbeddedBotTestDeploym_1712131019771-ESWEmbeddedBotTestDeploym1712131019771vf (max length=80)
Can we eliminate this error?

which MDAPI version used?

latest. Someone said that messaging embedded service deployment is not possible to migrate but I am trying not to lose hope. I opened a SF Support

I have opened a SF Support case on April 9th 2024.
Recently on Aug 23, 2024 there was published a known issue about this
https://issues.salesforce.com/issue/a028c00000zLLiS/
SF Support told me this set to be fixed in coming Winter release (252)
Workaround might be to use short Embedded service Deployment names until this is fixed or resolved

To resolve this, try shortening the label or use a different naming convention that adheres to the maximum length limit of 80 characters. This should help eliminate the error you're experiencing.

Is this written by AI? AI written posts are not allowed on this site (even if I wish they sometimes were).

yes, looks like it is.
